# How to access data from another operating system files

Tags: disk-management, filesystem

I'd like to transit from MacOS to Linux and want to move my data from a Mac to a new machine. What is the best tool to access Mac disks in elementary?

Answer (score 2):

elementary OS is able to **read** macOS HFS+ disks.

If you want to **write** to HFS+ disks from elementary OS, you need to install some [additional software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os).

Alternatively, to avoid any possible mess with HFS+ disks being written to by Linux (and if you don't plan to use your Mac drives for booting your Mac) you can reformat your macOS drives to exFAT file system, which has native read/write support in elementary OS, macOS and Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am looking forward to use elementary OS and have access to my old files.